# Excel INDEX MATCH Auto Fill

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the INDEX MATCH function on a table. This is my formula that I drag down and to the right.
=INDEX(tbl_depts,MATCH($B14,tbl_depts[DeptNum],0),MATCH(C$13,tbl_depts[#Headers],0))

And this is the table,
[Table of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odro8.png)

And this is where I'm inserting the formula. [Table with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgijG.png)

My question is, when I drag the auto fill to the right, I get #NA. And i can see why, my first MATCH argument is looking at the wrong table column. My question is why? Why does my lookup_array in the MATCH function shift.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an **Absolute** structured reference, that will maintain the column as you fill right,use instead the syntax:

```
tbl_depts[[DeptNum]:[DeptNum]]
```

Comment: What I've always found frustrating with tables is when you write a formula, you can't use the `F4` shortcut for absolute references. I never really found any reason why not, that shortcut doesn't seem to do something else in a table right?  Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @BruceWayne Sure would make things a **lot** easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! As I am learning Excel, no mention of table columns themselves being references. My world has opened up! Structured references, I will look into it. Unless is it made into an absolute reference, what is inherently excluded from this reference structure? Thank you.

Comment: @Megajuni I don't understand your question.

Comment: I was wondering about how I could have figured it out. I realized it was moving like a reference but I then how could I have known what the syntax was. I had another question, why doesn't tbl_depts[#Headers] shift down when I auto fill down to a row on the table. Thanks all the same

Comment: @Megajuni An internet search for something like `absolute structured references` might have revealed it. I suspect that the `#` fields are absolute references, but I've not seen that documented.